# Get Google calendar attendee updates from single event with push notfications

Tags: ruby, push-notification, google-calendar-api

My app created google calendar events, and I want to be notified when a user changes their invite status (accept or reject an event).

I've managed to setup a webhook that will notifiy me when ANYTHING changes on the user's calendar, but the response I get is just something's been updated.  Do I then have to update the entire calendar?  That seems nuts, I just want to watch specific events.

Comment: Check the setting if your calendar setting [`remindOnRespondedEventsOnly`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/settings) is set to `true`. Also from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update), set `sendNotifications` to `true` to send notifications about the event update (e.g. attendee's responses, title changes, etc.). Optional. The default is False.

Comment: To clarify, I have setup a notification channel to watch for updates on a calendar.  I want to watch specific events, not all of them.  The parameter you mention seems to be around event reminders, which is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `etag` for this. There is no way to watch specific events, but 
events has a version field that changes every time the resource changes and this is `etag`.

After webhook notifies you -for anything-
you can go and check for your special events and check if their `etag` have stayed same or not. If `etag` of a event has changed it means that event is modified.

For further information: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/version-resources